# How do you calculate the number of non-NA/null values used in the pandas DataFrame correlation function?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

According to the documentation for `pandas.DataFrame.corr`, it will "Compute pairwise correlation of columns, excluding NA/null values."
What is the simplest way to calculate the number of non-NA/null values used to calculate each correlation value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlation requires that **both** values are not null. We can use `broadcasting` to perform the pairwise check for all column combinations. The result is a matrix with the number of valid rows used in the correlation calculation.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(range(50)) + [np.NaN], (1000,6)),
                  columns=list('abcdef'))

arr = df.notnull().to_numpy().T
pd.DataFrame((arr & arr[:, None]).sum(2), index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)

#     a    b    c    d    e    f
#a  978  960  961  958  957  958
#b  960  982  964  962  959  960
#c  961  964  982  963  959  960
#d  958  962  963  980  957  958
#e  957  959  959  957  977  955
#f  958  960  960  958  955  978
```